# how to convert ISODate to unix epoch in mongo aggregate

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a field in mongo that is an ISODate. 
Is there an easy way to convert it to unix timestamps?

ie: 
 ISODate("2018-03-30T13:06:05.739-07:00") => 1522440365739

Comment: Do you know if there is anyway to do the opposite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out you'll need to first convert it to NumberLong using the subtract method:

ie:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
  $project: {date: {$subtract: ['$date', new Date(0)]}}
}])
```

If you want this to be a string, you'll need to convert that with substr:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
  $project: {
    date: {$substr: [{$subtract: ['$date', new Date(0)]}, 0, -1]}
  }
}])
```

Answer (score 6):

As of 4.0, you can use `$toDecimal`. `$toInt` would be too small for most timestamps nowadays.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
  $project: {
    date: {'$toDecimal': '$date'}
  }
}])
```

This returns unix timestamps in **milliseconds**.  To convert to seconds, use `$divide` by `1000`

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDecimal/